# When finding the mean of a Series of strings that are integers, why does it compute a float value that is wrong?

Tags: pandas

New to working with pandas, not sure why the mean() function outputs a weird value when using integers of strings.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(["1", "2"])
print(s.mean())
```

Output: `6.0`

Why does the output look like this?

I've tried finding the mean of Series where the integers are not used as strings and it came out as expected. But when putting quotes around the integers it outputs a unexpected value e.g. "1" and "2" I expect would be 1.5, but output is 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, using the `+` operator results in concatenating (putting the two strings one after the other):

Thus, `"1" + "2" = "12"`

I guess that after getting the `"12"`, pandas converts it somehow to `12` (integer), leading to `12/2 = 6`, which is the mean (given you have two elements in your series).